# Does a statement have to be true for it be objective?

Tags: objectivity, subjectivity

For example let's say someone said "Dad just got home" as joke but the father hadn't actually arrived, or "He told you to take the trash out" but that was a lie and didn't actually happen. How would such statements be classified?

Comment: They would be classified as objectively false.

Comment: See [objectivity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/objectivity): "based on facts". A false statement is not subjective: it does not express a "inner state of mind".

Comment: Some introductory material may help; see e.g. Stephen Gaukroger, [Objectivity: A Very Short Introduction (2012, Oxford University Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Objectivity_A_Very_Short_Introduction/zNgDYlWFvRQC): "The first understanding of objectivity is perhaps the most common one. It is that an objective judgement is a judgement that is free of prejudice and bias. [...] The second understanding is that an objective judgement is a judgement which is free of all assumptions and values. [...] 1/2

Comment: The third notion of objectivity is focused directly on how we arrive at our views or theories. It is that an objective procedure is one that allows us to decide between conflicting views or theories. [...] if we do away with all interpretations and assumptions, then we finally see things as they really are, independently of any subjective preconceptions we might bring to the judgement. That would connect truth and objectivity." 2/2

Comment: Review your theories of truth. Objectivity is about how truth is in someway independent of any one person's truth semantics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Major_theories

Answer (score 1):

Objectivity means being impartial, trying to correct for any cognitive bias, or for mood, say. To make an objective statement is to take a neutral 'everyman' perspective, not related to personal and subjective experiences and views. Objective vs subjective distinctions belong to discussions of bias.

The statements you mention belong in a different context: finny vs not funny; true vs lie. So that's how you would classify them. If say a court case happened around the events, police and lawyers would interview everyone involved and look for evidence, to build an objective account of events that was independent of any one person's account.